# ios swift local notifications no sound

Tags: ios, arrays, uilocalnotification

Iam trying to make a regular UILocalNotification with default sound

this is my function

```
func makeLocalNotificationForNow(str : String , id : String)
{
let notification = UILocalNotification()


notification.alertBody = str // text that will be displayed in the notification
notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5) // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function I put

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Note : I also use parse push notifications

when I make the notification , it appears but without an alert or sound (I need to swipe the from top to see the notification 
what's wrong ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a stupid mistake , the problem was my phone , I changed the phone and it all worked

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know notifications only make a sound when the app is in the background, meaning quit you app, put your phone on locked mode and send a notification through the parse website, then you should hear the sound, if not, check the settings on the app you're making to see if sound alerts are enabled, and last resource, check that your phone is not on vibrate only